# Why daterangepicker is not showing after click?

Tags: javascript

I have a page where you can search a name using a autocomplete textbox, when you select a name. A java script calls a PHP script and that page shows in a `<div>`. On the page is a daterangepicker, but this is not working. When I test daterangepicker on a blank page the script is functionally normally.

Can somebody help me to fix the script.

Index.php

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="button"> Klik hier</button>
<div id="formulier"></div>

<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#button').click(function(){  
           var name_id = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"embedded.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#formulier').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

embedded.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="daterangepicker.css" />

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>


<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 15%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('D-M-YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('D-M-YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Vandaag': [moment(), moment()],
           'Gisteren': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Afgelopen 7 dagen': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Afgelopen 30 dagen': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Deze maand': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Vorige maand': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

[image: embeded.php]
[image: test.php]

Comment: Try not putting the daterangepicker in the file being loaded via AJAX. Instead include the script tags in the main file. Then in your ajax success after applying the HTML, that is when you call the daterangepicker.

Comment: I have tried that but it's still not working.

Comment: Can you post that code? Because that is where your problem is happening. When embedding the date range picker in search.php, it won't be calling the javascript from within search.php. Also, search.php doesn't need to have full HTML tags (head/html/body) as it is being embedded within a HTML page.

Comment: Hi @imvain2 i have updated my post. :)

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi @Marvin , could you maybe try to [make a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me? For example: [create a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can better help you debug your problem. It's hard to have a go at your problem without an easy way to reproduce it.

Comment: @JiFus i gave updatet my post with a mimial example.
When i go to  embedded.php the page is functional normally, but when i click the button it is not working. See my print screens.

Comment: @Marvin It's probably an issue with the fact you're loading two different types of jQuery, which might give issues. Did you check the developer console? Also: is there a specific reason why you're fetching an entire page and throwing it in the DOM?

Comment: ncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:4:17)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.4.0.js:3557)
    at process (jquery-3.4.0.js:3625)

Comment: When I click two times on the button the datepicker shows up.